# Cannot commit or see changes in SCM pane of VS Code - one project only

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-git

I have recently stopped seeing updates in the SCM pane in VS Code for one project only. It detects the repository, detects the changes, I can go into the ... menu to perform the usual tasks I do in the pane like Stage, Commit, and Push, but neither the Message nor Changes sections appear in the pane.

I have tried closing and reopening the repositories as well as disabling the Git extensions and restarting, enabling the Git extensions and restarting again; neither works. My other projects all seem to work normally, it's just this one. I saw some of the other answers on similar topics here, but none seemed to address this issue (as it is connected and tracks changes, the pane just isn't working), so would appreciate some guidance for my specific issue. Below is an example of the difference in two of my projects with changes:

[image: VSCode projects where one works and one doesn't]

Comment: Extensions I can't say. As far as I know they're all global? The extensions that come up under the extensions tab are the same for both. And no, I open by folder and each folder has a single repo. I DO sometimes open files from other folders (e.g. where I'm implementing some similar code), but I've done that in both projects and it's just the one that's not working.

Comment: extensions can be disabled and enabled on a per-workspace basis. I take it by the fact that you didn't know that you've never done that so that's not relevant here :P